# Python Regex: find all lines that start with '{' and end with '}'

Tags: python, regex

I am receiving data over a socket, a bunch of JSON strings. However, I receive a set amount of bytes, so sometimes the last of my JSON strings is cut-off. I will typically get the following:

```
{"pitch":-30.778193,"yaw":-124.63285,"roll":-8.977466}
{"pitch":-30.856342,"yaw":-124.57556,"roll":-7.7220345}
{"pitch":-31.574106,"yaw":-124.65623,"roll":-7.911794}
{"pitch":-30.479567,"yaw":-124.24301,"roll":-8.730827}
{"pitch":-29.30239,"yaw":-123.97949,"roll":-8.134723}
{"pitch":-29.84712,"yaw":-124.584465,"roll":-8.588374}
{"pitch":-31.072054,"yaw":-124.707466,"roll":-8.877062}
{"pitch":-31.493435,"yaw":-124.75457,"roll":-9.019922}
{"pitch":-29.591925,"yaw":-124.960815,"roll":-9.379437}
{"pitch":-29.37105,"yaw":-125.14427,"roll":-9.642341}
{"pitch":-29.483717,"yaw":-125.16528,"roll":-9.687177}
{"pitch":-30.903332,"yaw":-124.603935,"roll":-9.423098}
{"pitch":-30.211857,"yaw":-124.471664,"roll":-9.116135}
{"pitch":-30.837414,"yaw":-125.18984,"roll":-9.824204}
{"pitch":-30.526165,"yaw":-124.85788,"roll":-9.158611}
{"pitch":-30.333513,"yaw":-123.68705,"roll":-7.9481263}
{"pitch":-30.903502,"yaw":-123.78847,"roll":-8.209373}
{"pitch":-31.194769,"yaw":-124.79708,"roll":-8.709783}
{"pitch":-30.816765,"yaw":-125
```

With Python, I would like to create a string array of the first 18 complete `{ data... }` strings.

Here is what I have tried: `cleanData = re.search('{.*}', data)` but it seems like this is only giving me the very first `{ data... }` entry. How can I get the full string array of complete { } sets?

Answer (score 6):

To get all, you can use `re.finditer` or `re.findall`.

```
>>> re.findall(r'{.*}', s)
['{"pitch":-30.778193,"yaw":-124.63285,"roll":-8.977466}', '{"pitch":-30.856342,"yaw":-124.57556,"roll":-7.7220345}', '{"pitch":-31.574106,"yaw":-124.65623,"roll":-7.911794}', '{"pitch":-30.479567,"yaw":-124.24301,"roll":-8.730827}', '{"pitch":-29.30239,"yaw":-123.97949,"roll":-8.134723}', '{"pitch":-29.84712,"yaw":-124.584465,"roll":-8.588374}', '{"pitch":-31.072054,"yaw":-124.707466,"roll":-8.877062}', '{"pitch":-31.493435,"yaw":-124.75457,"roll":-9.019922}', '{"pitch":-29.591925,"yaw":-124.960815,"roll":-9.379437}', '{"pitch":-29.37105,"yaw":-125.14427,"roll":-9.642341}', '{"pitch":-29.483717,"yaw":-125.16528,"roll":-9.687177}', '{"pitch":-30.903332,"yaw":-124.603935,"roll":-9.423098}', '{"pitch":-30.211857,"yaw":-124.471664,"roll":-9.116135}', '{"pitch":-30.837414,"yaw":-125.18984,"roll":-9.824204}', '{"pitch":-30.526165,"yaw":-124.85788,"roll":-9.158611}', '{"pitch":-30.333513,"yaw":-123.68705,"roll":-7.9481263}', '{"pitch":-30.903502,"yaw":-123.78847,"roll":-8.209373}', '{"pitch":-31.194769,"yaw":-124.79708,"roll":-8.709783}']
>>>
```

OR

```
>>> [x.group() for x in re.finditer(r'{.*}', s)]
['{"pitch":-30.778193,"yaw":-124.63285,"roll":-8.977466}', '{"pitch":-30.856342,"yaw":-124.57556,"roll":-7.7220345}', '{"pitch":-31.574106,"yaw":-124.65623,"roll":-7.911794}', '{"pitch":-30.479567,"yaw":-124.24301,"roll":-8.730827}', '{"pitch":-29.30239,"yaw":-123.97949,"roll":-8.134723}', '{"pitch":-29.84712,"yaw":-124.584465,"roll":-8.588374}', '{"pitch":-31.072054,"yaw":-124.707466,"roll":-8.877062}', '{"pitch":-31.493435,"yaw":-124.75457,"roll":-9.019922}', '{"pitch":-29.591925,"yaw":-124.960815,"roll":-9.379437}', '{"pitch":-29.37105,"yaw":-125.14427,"roll":-9.642341}', '{"pitch":-29.483717,"yaw":-125.16528,"roll":-9.687177}', '{"pitch":-30.903332,"yaw":-124.603935,"roll":-9.423098}', '{"pitch":-30.211857,"yaw":-124.471664,"roll":-9.116135}', '{"pitch":-30.837414,"yaw":-125.18984,"roll":-9.824204}', '{"pitch":-30.526165,"yaw":-124.85788,"roll":-9.158611}', '{"pitch":-30.333513,"yaw":-123.68705,"roll":-7.9481263}', '{"pitch":-30.903502,"yaw":-123.78847,"roll":-8.209373}', '{"pitch":-31.194769,"yaw":-124.79708,"roll":-8.709783}']
>>>
```

Comment: I don't think this is actually what OP wants, but it's worth noting that if you actually want just the first 18 matches you could use [`itertools.islice`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice)`(re.finditer(r'{.*}', s), 18)`. Also, to ensure that the `{`/`}` start/end a line, you could use `re.finditer(r'^{.*}$', s, re.MULTILINE)`.

Comment: I think this is the OP want though I am not sure. But I don't think `itertools.islice` is need here. The `finditer` get all the matches and there is no need to slice. Besides, it only returns a generator, you still need to loop through it to get the results.

Comment: I agree I don't think this is what OP wants, but it's similar enough that it's possible. And if you want a list instead of an iterator just call `list()` on it.

Comment: A `list()` is not enough. You still have to call `.group()` on each element of the list.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. The "18" is arbitrary, it could be 17 or 19 so I don't want to go by that. I will try your first solution, it seems ideal.

Answer (score 4):

You need [`re.findall()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) (or `re.finditer`)

```
>>> import re
>>> for r in re.findall(r'{.*}', data)[:18]:
    print r


{"pitch":-30.778193,"yaw":-124.63285,"roll":-8.977466}
{"pitch":-30.856342,"yaw":-124.57556,"roll":-7.7220345}
{"pitch":-31.574106,"yaw":-124.65623,"roll":-7.911794}
{"pitch":-30.479567,"yaw":-124.24301,"roll":-8.730827}
{"pitch":-29.30239,"yaw":-123.97949,"roll":-8.134723}
{"pitch":-29.84712,"yaw":-124.584465,"roll":-8.588374}
{"pitch":-31.072054,"yaw":-124.707466,"roll":-8.877062}
{"pitch":-31.493435,"yaw":-124.75457,"roll":-9.019922}
{"pitch":-29.591925,"yaw":-124.960815,"roll":-9.379437}
{"pitch":-29.37105,"yaw":-125.14427,"roll":-9.642341}
{"pitch":-29.483717,"yaw":-125.16528,"roll":-9.687177}
{"pitch":-30.903332,"yaw":-124.603935,"roll":-9.423098}
{"pitch":-30.211857,"yaw":-124.471664,"roll":-9.116135}
{"pitch":-30.837414,"yaw":-125.18984,"roll":-9.824204}
{"pitch":-30.526165,"yaw":-124.85788,"roll":-9.158611}
{"pitch":-30.333513,"yaw":-123.68705,"roll":-7.9481263}
{"pitch":-30.903502,"yaw":-123.78847,"roll":-8.209373}
{"pitch":-31.194769,"yaw":-124.79708,"roll":-8.709783}
```

Answer (score 0):

Extracting lines that start and end with a specific character can be done without any regex, use `str.startswith` and `str.endswith` methods when iterating through the lines in a file:

```
results = []
with open(filepath, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('{') and line.rstrip('\n').endswith('}'):
            results.append(line.rstrip('\n'))
```

Note the `.rstrip('\n')` is used before `.endswith` to make sure the final newline does not interfere with the `}` check at the end of the string.